# Database Design / Document Relationship Issue

Tags: database, design-patterns, database-design, model-view-controller, relational-database

I am currently designing and developing a document management system, and have come across an issue that is causing me major headaches. More than anything this is just a bit of a sanity check...

Basically the system stores documents, which can have a relationship to any of the following entities:

- A business only
- A business and multiple contacts
- A consumer only (single person, not related to business)
- Multiple consumers

The above alignments are used for searching and indexing documents, as well as storing business and contact details for repeated use.

Let's just say NewOrder.pdf is a contract to purchase a new car, the following combinations could exist:

1. NewOrder.pdf - aligned to business 'Acme Pty Ltd'
2. NewOrder.pdf - aligned to business 'Acme Pty Ltd' and contact 'John Doe'
3. NewOrder.pdf - aligned to business 'Acme Pty Ltd' and contacts 'John Doe' and 'Wayne Kerr'
4. NewOrder.pdf - aligned to consumer 'Adam Smith'
5. NewOrder.pdf - aligned to consumers 'Adam Smith' and 'Sue Smith'

As an example, let's take relationships (1), (3) and (4) from above. The only way that's crossed my mind how to achieve the relationship is to align documents as follows....

[image]

The above is very dirty, as I'm creating tables with duplicate information or blank entries.

Would love some comments, feedback and more importantly suggestions :thumbup:

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid duplicate data - it'll end in tears. Maybe consider join tables? ie.

```
table.documentBusinessRelationship:    
    DocumentID
    BusinessID
```

That way you only have an row in the database for any documents that actually have relationships to businesses.

And another join table

```
table.documentContactRelationship
    DocumentID
    ContactID
```

Maybe the biggest problems with these sorts of join tables is that it can make querying a bit more complicated - but at least you maintain some kind of normal form, with no data duplication or empty placeholder columns.